# Not able to install Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Cors from NuGet

Tags: asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2013, cors

I just upgrade my project from Visual Studio from 2010 to 2013 to support Cross-Origin Resource Sharing (CORS) in my WebApi. 
Now when I am installing Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Cors package from NuGet then I am getting following error.

I am using Visual Studio 2013, Asp.Net MVC 5

```
PM> Install-Package Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Cors
Attempting to resolve dependency 'Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Core (≥ 5.2.3 && < 5.3.0)'.
Attempting to resolve dependency 'Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Client (≥ 5.2.3)'.
Install-Package : An item with the same key has already been added.
At line:1 char:1
+ Install-Package Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Cors
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Install-Package], ArgumentException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NuGetCmdletUnhandledException,NuGet.PowerShell.Commands.InstallPackageCommand
```

Comment: So it says you have already added that item, I think you can try uninstalling the same item and then try a install

Comment: But when I am trying to implement namespace in my controller, It is throwing error. I check my Package folder, where I did not found this folder and dll. Even I try to run Uninstall-Package Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Cors, It is also throwing an error.

Comment: Not sure what else might be the issue. Add a bounty more people will show up

Comment: How does your `packages.config` file look like?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had exact the same problem with another NuGet library.

Please try this steps:

**1. Updates**

Proof if your installed NuGet version is on the newest version

**2. Clear cache**

Use the NuGet command prompt and clear the cache:

You can list the local caches with this command:

`nuget locals all -list`

You can clear all caches with this command:

`nuget locals all -clear`

**3. Check cache**

The NuGet Cache is simply a folder on your computer, you can proof delete the remaining files manually under *%LOCALAPPDATA%\NuGet\Cache*.

Or just run this in administrator CMD:

`del %LOCALAPPDATA%\NuGet\Cache\*.nupkg /q`

Answer (score 1):

The message says the package is already installed.
try uninstall before to re-install:

> Uninstall-Package Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Cors

Answer (score 0):

If that can help someone else, I tried to follow the steps from Steffen Mangold but that's wasn't working completely.

If you have an assembly error like:

`System.Web.Http, Version=5.0.0.0`

after doing this command `Install-Package Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Cors`

Try that :

**1 - Run this in administrator CMD**

`del %LOCALAPPDATA%\NuGet\Cache\*.nupkg /q`

**2 - Run this in the Package manager console**

`Install-Package Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi`

That will install missing assemblies and fix the error.

Answer (score 0):

Check the package source.

Go to tools, click on Nuget Package Manager and click on Package Manager settings.

Then go to Package Sources subsection under the Nuget Package Manager section.

In my case the source was initially pointing to a folder on my local machine.
So just add another package source with the following details.
Name :  nuget.org
Source :  https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json